# Find $a > 0$ values s.t. $\sum_{n = 2}^\infty \ln\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n^a}\right)$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

How can i find all $a > 0$ values s.t. the following sum is finite?

$$\sum_{n = 2}^\infty \ln\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n^a}\right)$$

I was able to show the sum converges absolutly for $a > 1$ by using the compairson test.

How can I find all $a$ values s.t. the sum is conditionally convergent?

What I usually do in these kind of questions, Is to use comparison test and find the constrains on $a$ but i can't get it working.

Any hints will be appericiated.

Comment: Just use the limit comparaison test with $a_n= \frac{(-1)^n}{n^a}-\ln\left(  1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n^a} \right) ; b_n= \frac{1}{n^{2a}}$.

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen What led you chose that $b_n$ for comparison?

Comment: Because $b_n$ should be chosen to be a positive sequence such that $a_n/b_n$ converges to a non-zero limit and $(b_n)$ is simple enough for reasoning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a fixed $a > 0$, applying Taylor's theorem on the interval $[-1/2^{a}, 1/2^{a}]$ we get $$\ln\Big(1+\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{a}}\Big) = \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{a}}-\frac{1}{2(1+\xi_{n})^{2}}\frac{1}{n^{2a}}$$ for some $\xi_{n}$ between $0$ and $(-1)^{n}/n^a$. Also note that $$\frac{2^{2a}}{2(2^{a}+1)^{2}}\frac{1}{n^{2a}} \leq \frac{1}{2(1+\xi_{n})^{2}}\frac{1}{n^{2a}} \leq \frac{2^{2a}}{2(2^{a}-1)^{2}}\frac{1}{n^{2a}}.$$ Thus, $$\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2(1+\xi_{n})^{2}}\frac{1}{n^{2a}}$$ converges for $a > 1/2$ and diverges for $0 < a \leq 1/2$. By the alternating series test, $\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}/n^a$ converges for all $a > 0$. Thus, the original sum converges for $a > 1/2$.

Comment: Nice solution. Why taylor's tho? I would not think of it even in a year

Comment: @MStudent $\log(1+(-1)^{n}/n^a)$ should behave roughly like $(-1)^{n}/n^{a}$ as $n$ gets large. I would say the idea behind my answer is exactly the same as indicated in the comment by Paresseux Nguyen.